# Why newline \n is not working php form submission

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using the following to send an email from a form:

```
<?php
$mail->Body = "New application от,\r\n
               Name: $name\r\n
               Gender $gender\r\n
               Phone: $phone\r\n
               Email: $email\r\n
               Program: $program";

?>
```

When I receive the email everything is one line. Without the "\r\n"

Comment: where's the rest of the code? The method as to how it's sent is unknown.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"When I receive the email everything is one line. Without the "\r\n""*.

Comment: I guess you left the question, so have I now. You will need to take it up with the answer given. I asked for clarification but received no response.

Comment: I am receiving the email and all the content is in one line what other clarification do you need ?

Comment: I said I left the question and you bring me back here based on what you wrote and not what I asked. Again, take it up with the answer below, thank you.

Comment: You're not being very cooperative as per [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746306/why-newline-n-is-not-working-php-form-submission?noredirect=1#comment76473690_44746306). You have another answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the rest of your code, but I'd guess that you're calling `$mail->isHTML()`, in which case you line breaks will not be shown in a rendered message, regardless of whether they are `\n` or `\r\n`. Add `<br>` tags to your body, and note that you don't need to add any more line breaks because your string already contains them:

```
$mail->Body = "New application от,<br>
           Name: $name<br>
           Gender $gender<br>
           Phone: $phone<br>
           Email: $email<br>
           Program: $program";
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked with a <br>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PHP_EOL` for this purposes (due to cross-platform compatibility).

```
echo "line 1".PHP_EOL."line 2".PHP_EOL;
<?php
$mail->Body = "New application от,".PHP_EOL."Name: $name".PHP_EOL."and so on";

?>
```

Comment: Nope. It's because the body content is HTML.

Comment: @Synchro To which we don't really know since I asked them [in this comment earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746306/why-newline-n-is-not-working-php-form-submission?noredirect=1#comment76473690_44746306) and got back no update to the question. So this answer could be just as wrong or right as yours.

Comment: By elimination, no. If he's on Windows the line breaks will be native `/r/n`, so in a plain-text context he'd have double line spacing (the explicit and implicit breaks). On Linux context the text would have both `\n` and `\r\n` breaks, which would result in at least single breaks, if not double. Neither line break format would result in no breaks. The only other reason I can think of for line breaks being ignored is that it's HTML, hence my answer.